# DbMigration & DbModelBuilder behavior before compilation in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have an attribute as such:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class IsUnicodeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public bool IsUnicode { set; get; }

    public IsUnicodeAttribute(bool isUnicode)
    {
        this.IsUnicode = isUnicode;
    }
}
```

And I have it read at the DbModelBuilder as:

```
modelBuilder.Properties<String>()
            .Having(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<IsUnicodeAttribute>().FirstOrDefault())
            .Configure((config, attr) => config.IsUnicode(attr.IsUnicode));
```

While not having a database yet, I enabled migrations and added the first migration. However, I noticed that there are not indications of those columns marked with the attribute as being Unicode in the migration file created.

Is it that I made an error in the configuration, or that because it is not at runtime to know the value of the `IsUnicode` property of the attribute, or is it that Unicode is the default?

I am using EF 6.1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked the database after its creation, and found that in fact `NVARCHAR` is the data type of all `string` properties I declared in the class model without needing to specify `IsUnicode` over them.

This looks to be the default for SQL Server provider at least.

Edit: I used `modelBuilder.Entity<T>().Property(a => a.Message).IsUnicode(false)` and the migration file created actually specified that. It turns out that strings are Unicode by default, so there is no need to specify that in the migration file, and it looks like they are `NVARCHAR` by default; not fixed size.